# How to display all the post when i load a page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a product page and i have put a dropdown displaying the categories of the post.So i want to display all the products by default wen i load product page.The ajax call is triggerd only wen i select a category from the dropdown.Is there a way to display all the post wen i load the page?

[image]

The dropdown has 3 options selct category(default),food items, and hospitality items

-Front End Code

```py
<select class="event-dropdown"> 
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr(__('Select category')); ?></option> 
    <?php 
        $categories = get_categories(); 
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $option .= '<option value="'.$category->slug.'">';
            $option .= $category->cat_name;
            $option .= '</option>';
        }
        echo $option;
    ?>
</select>
</div>     
<div class="test"></div><!---test --->

<script>
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
$('.event-dropdown').on('change', function()
  {
      var cat_slug= this.value;
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data:{
      'action': 'my_action',
      'whatever': cat_slug,
    },
    success: function( data ) {
      $(".test").html(data);
    }
    })
  });
</script>
```

Backend-Funtions.php

```py
     add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
      function my_action() {
        global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

        $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];

          $args = array(      
                  'category_name' =>$whatever,  
                  'post_type' => 'ProductsNew',
                  'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
                  'order'=>'ASC'
                        );
             $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                        // The Query
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );




                        $total = $the_query->post_count;

                        if ( $i == 0 ) echo '<div class="row">';

                        // The Loop
                        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                            $the_query->the_post();?>

          <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            <div class="reduce">
             <div class="card">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail('',array('class'=>'img-responsive'));?>

                <h3><?php the_field('product_title')?></h3>
                <p class="price"><?php the_field('product_price');?> </p>
                <div class="discription">  
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>     
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <?php $i++;
         if($i == $total){
        echo '</div>';
       } else  {
            if( $i % 3 ==0){ echo'</div><div class="row">';  }

               }
                          }
                          /* Restore original Post Data */
                          wp_reset_postdata();
                          wp_die();
                        } else {
                          // no posts found
                          wp_die();
                        }  

}
```

When I open the products page it does not display all the post,only once i select the the category it displays the post.And then if i select the selcect category option it display all post.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to show all posts is similar to your `WP_Query($args)`. Try taking that same `$args` variable and using it with the Wordpress function `get_posts()`. Then you get loop through what's returned with a `foreach` loop. Here's a visual:

```
$args = array(      
 'category_name' =>$whatever,  
 'post_type' => 'ProductsNew',
 'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
 'order'=>'ASC'
);

$product_array = get_posts($args);

foreach($product_array as $product) {
 // display your product cards
}
```

Feel free throw this anywhere, maybe directly after `.col-sm-4` or after `.event-dropdown`.

[get_posts docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: if i put this code in the front end it will display all the post every time. And when i select a category it displays the category post after this post have been diplayed .I want it to work with select category option.if i select hospitality items it should only display hospitality items

Comment: It display all post if i select the (select category option) in drop down but while loading the product page it does not work